# I need help to save images in cloudkit

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit

In my application the user is able to select an image within his gallery and save it in a UIMAGEVIEW now the problem is that when I save that image in cloudkit gives me the following error
"Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled"

```
 @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
    let codig = code.text
    let precio = price.text
    let imagen = imageCover.image

    let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Productos", zoneID: zona.zoneID)
        record.setObject(codig as __CKRecordObjCValue?, forKey: "code")
        record.setObject(precio as __CKRecordObjCValue?, forKey: "costo") 
        let mngr = FileManager.default
        let dir = mngr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let file = dir[0].appendingPathComponent("myimage").path

        imagen?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)?.write(to: file as! URL)
        let imgURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: file)
        let imageAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: imgURL)

        record.setObject(imageAsset, forKey: "imagecover")

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        database.save(record) { (record, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Save")
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+can+throw%2C+but+it+is+not+marked+with+%27try%27) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following line:

```
imagen?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)?.write(to: file as! URL)
```

As you can see in the documentation(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779858-write) the function `write(to:)` can throw an error. You need to handle the error by either ignoring it

```
try? <function that throws error>
```

or by catching it using a `do..catch` block:

```
do {
   try <function that throws error>
} catch {
   // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now it gives me the following error:  Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) . 

try? imagenes?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)?.write(to: file as! URL)

Comment: @PabloPiedrasanta Try to catch the error to see what went wrong. You are using an optional image, it might be nil.